# Suddenly Dell Inspirion 5547 battery shows permanent failure

Tags: hardware-failure

Previously my laptop is running on Windows 10. But on Friday night I thought to switch to Ubuntu and replaced my OS with Ubuntu Kylin. After replacing OS it works fine for 2 days but today when I am turning it on then it shows a message of battery permanent failure, needs to be replaced. Also after replacing OS I used my laptop continuously for 40 hrs... Because I have to recover some of my data.. I used testdisk to recover my data.

Do I really need to replace my battery with new one? Also battery voltage is showing 12 volts. BIOS also shows same message. And I already tried to remove battery and then keeping power button pressed for 30 seconds and than again put it ... But nothing works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the battery going bad? Yes.
Do you need to replace it immediately? Depends, but mostly no.

We've had many (as in hundreds of) Dell laptops at our work and battery failure is not uncommon at around three - four years especially if the computer has been used as a "desktop replacement" and/or the battery has been in constant charge/drain -cycle (ie. not removed while computer is in use and connected to the charger for prolonged periods)..

If the BIOS is telling you it should be replaced it means that it is nearing the end of it's life and the capacity has been reduced noticeably.

If you pull up Ubuntu's battery properties it can, most of the time, tell you more accurately the actual battery data (actual / nominal Wh's, etc) than Windows 10 and the BIOS (which in Dell's is pretty parse about battery statistics). I find that comparing the "Energy (design)", which tells the Wh's the battery had "when new" and the "Energy when full", which tells the current maximum charge are usually pretty accurate depictions of the battery's status.

If you don't need to use the battery for anything more than moving the computer around the house, for example, you don't really need to replace it immediately. It will keep going bad and in the end it will hold a charge that can keep the computer running for a couple of minutes, tops. It might also enter the "broken" state (if it's one of the older model batteries with LEDs they will just blink when you press the charge checking button), in which case it will not charge or even power the computer on anymore.

If you need the computer anywhere where you cannot use the charger to power it - I suggest you replace the battery as soon as possible.

Comment: For your first question it's No... my battery is working fine. It's giving a backup of 3 to 4 hrs. when fully charged.
Yes i only need battery just to move my laptop around house. I don't have any problem to replace it with new one... my only concern is to know the reason why it suddenly fails permanently. Because if i purchase a new one and again it will show that failure message than it's totally wastage of my money... Also for your information my laptop is 3 year old.

Comment: Ok, if the computer works for 3+ hours with the battery alone, you might have a (nearly) dead cell in it. Did you ever leave the computer unused for long (weeks-month) periods of time with the battery connected (Lithium batteries can "die" if left to drain completely empty). It might also be a diagnostic problem, though; take out the battery and hold down the power button for 20-30 seconds to clear the power diagnostics. If that doen't help, you might wish to check if you can simply turn off the error message in BIOS.